# Simple IPv6 Global Unicast question

Tags: ip, networking, ipv6, ip-address, prefix

I was reading [this](https://www.omnisecu.com/tcpip/ipv6/global-unicast-ipv6-addresses.php) article which states:

> RFC 3587 states that out of the 128 bits in IPv6 addresses, left most
> three bits are must be fixed as 001. Remaining 45 bits are reserved
> for global routing prefix. 16 bits after that can be used for
> subnetting and the 64 remaning bits are the host bits.
>
> The first fixed three bits (001) and the 45 bit global routing prefix
> (45+3 = 48 bits) together can be assigned to an organization as their
> IPv6 prefix. Since the leftmost three bits are reserved as "001" for
> Global unicast IPv6 addresses, the range of Global Unicast Addresses
> available now are from 2000 to 3FFF, as shown below.

I am a bit confused as to how the **001** bits means Global Unicast Addresses always start with a **2** or a **3**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left most 001 are fixed, this means the left most nibble can be:

**001**0 = 0x2

**001**1 = 0x3

The 4th left most bit is not fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the most clear answer I have read in all my time trying to understand this!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that four bits are used for each hexadecimal digit. `0010` and `0011` are the bits for the first hexadecimal digit in `/3`, and the correspond to `2` and `3` in hexadecimal. The first three bits are unchangeable for `/3`, but the fourth bit can be `0` or `1`.

The current Global IPv6 address range (IPv6 addresses use hexadecimal numbers, unlike IPv4) is assigned from `2000::/3`, so you can have the first hexadecimal digit as `2` or `3`.